# BufferedReader is not parsing ascii control characters when using readline

Tags: java, ascii, bufferedreader, control-characters

I am trying split some strings with ascii control characters from a text file and ultimately have the following output:

```
Record1
Record2
Record3
Record4
```

My text file looks like this in notepad++:

[image]

But when using `BufferedReader` to get the line from the text file it does not catch the control characters from the file. My code looks like this:

```
File file = new File("Records.txt");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);

String text = bufferedReader.readLine();

System.out.println(text);
```

and the result of my sysout looks like this:

```
Record1Record2Record3Record4
```

Should I be using ISO-8859-1 instead of UTF-8?

Comment: you could have just tried it with `ISO-8859-1`. what are the characters?

Comment: I actually tried with ISO-8859-1 is still have the same result. If I am not mistaken these characters are ascii control codes. https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html the GS is ctl-] is notepad ++

Comment: from my google search it should be a unit separator (ctrl ^_) char 31. its not a visible character. as you want to replace it with a linebreak, replace it with such

Comment: But the goal is not to modify the file in anyway. Is it really impossible to parse those characters into Java?

Comment: you do read them but they are no line breaks and tehrefore your output will always be 1 line. only line feed and carriage return start a new line. also you don't modify the file. you read it, modify it in memory and then write it

Comment: @Nomad what is the file's encoding? Notepad++ shows it in the bottom right.

Comment: Can you try wtiting the output to a text file rather than printing on console. Set the encoding of the file same as input file.

Comment: You should find out: 1) what *bytes* are in the file (use a hex editor); 2) whether the problem is in display or parsing - dump the UTF-16 code unit value from each `char` in the string that you're reading.

Comment: @JonSkeet the problem is in display i'd say. If my idea is correct, then my answer would apply

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: I'd prefer not to guess, really. The OP should do the diagnostic work here.

Answer (score 2):

You can read each record separately using the US character as a delimiter:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("Records.txt")).useDelimiter("\u001F");
while (scanner.hasNext())
    System.out.println(scanner.next());
```

Output:

```
Record1
Record2
Record3
Record4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "test" + (char) 31 + "test2";
String c = String.valueOf((char) 31);
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(s.split(c)));
```

assuming 31 is the right character (unit separator), this code will split at every occurence of it and therefore it should satisfy your needs

Answer (score 0):

A sidenote: System.out.print .. stuff is not forcibly reliable when applied to "raw" data with control characters especially if displayed on the terminal (cmd window).

Answer (score 0):

Using the character value of the unit separator gave me a hint. This is what I did from my end

```
    File file = new File("Records.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis, "ISO-8859-1");

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String text = bufferedReader.readLine();

    Character delim = '\037';

    String[] records = text.split(delim.toString());

    for (String string : records) {
        System.out.println(string);
    }
```

and got my expected output:

```
Record1
Record2
Record3
Record4
```